# move autocommit from driver to batis

Tags: spring, transactions, mybatis

My web app was initially made for `db2`/`derby` and relied on default autocommit=true.

Mybatis Mapper methods that modify data are *sometimes* grouped in one transaction using
`TransactionTemplate.execute()`, but most non-DML methods are executed as is.

I recently found that nested SQL queries (`<association>` with `select` attribute) fail, because closing one cursor closes all cursors in current connection.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21420760

So I need these changes:

- turn driver autocommit off when a connection is borrowed from the pool
- If a method is a DML method and there's no transaction context, mybatis should commit

The problem is that the only place in `Spring` that calls `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` is `DataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction()`

How to make all Mapper methods transactional?